# Linux Regular User Chown

Tags: linux

I'm using **Capistrano** (*Railsless*) to deploy a PHP project. I am doing the SSH through a regular user account. My problem is when i deploy I need to run `chown -R www-data:www-data` on a folder (which the user is a group of).

I must also call `chmod g+w` on the same folder.

I do not want to make this user an administrator. 
Is this possible to do?

`I'm using Debian Wheezy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am doing the SSH through a regular user account.

You shouldn't. It's a security policy. If you do you are going to need to set the rights manually. Not every regular user on the machine should be able to deploy by default.

Try deploying the files using the user which is the owner/makes use of the folder (most of the time the user which has the application server running). Anything that you use to deploy your code needs to use that login, from Maven to even simple scp. You don't have to change privileges afterwards then.

Other option is to write a script which will be executed from an elevated user. This script will check a certain directory for file changes. If new files were added then it copies them to the deployment directory, sets the rights automatically and then removes them from the "transition" directory.